# android SharedPreferences null tag

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I found in my `SharedPreferences`:

```
<map>
    <boolean name="MY_BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
    <null name="CURRENT_USER"/>
</map>
```

when:

```
sp.edit().putString(CURRENT_USER,myMap.get("SOME_KEY")).commit();
```

CURRENT_USER is a static final String with value
myMap is `Map<String, String>`

**Whats is the meaning of null tag? Is it some bug?**

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Please explain better.

Comment: Is that null tag a good android SharedPreferences behaviour?

Comment: I think `myMap.get("SOME_KEY")` is returning null. log the output of `myMap.get("SOME_KEY")` before putting it in your shared preference.

Comment: Let's assume myMap.get("SOME_KEY") do return null, shouldn't it be <string name="CURRENT_USER" value="null">?

Comment: I don't know what will happen in that case. maybe in both cases, when you try to get value form your shared preferences , it will return null and if so, there is no difference for you. when you put null value, you will get null value.

Comment: it seems to be a bug in lower APIs. Similar problems here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/JpDzZtbrjfA and here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/JpDzZtbrjfA